Is there a way to make two different Qt UIs use the saem instance of a particular widget
I have an app (github.com/rparkins999/sqliteman if you want to know) which has several dialogs defined by QT creator which use the same subdialog (queryeditordialog.ui). I want the information that the user puts into the subdialog to be persistent so that if the user gets it wrong they can re-request the top level dialog and edit the information rather than inputting it all over again. I can arrange for the subdialog to be persistent when its owning dialog isn't visible, but I would like to use the same instance of the subdialog for all of the owning dialogs. I think I could do this by constructing all the owning dialogs using code rather than using Qt Creator, but I would prefer to do it in Qt Creator if that is possible because it's easier to mainatin.

I found a partial workaround for this problem. The design for the shared subdialog can be done with Qt Creator, but I still have to write the code. If I make static the member variables which contain information which I want to share, then they will have the same content for all instances of the subdialog. However if more than one instance is visible at a time, updating one doesn't update the others. You also have to be careful with initialisation.
